# create archive with several folders without parent paths

Tags: linux, zip, tar

I have folders

```
/path1/folder1
/path1/folder2
/path1/folder3
/path2/folder4
/path2/folder5
/path2/folder6
```

How can I compress folder1-folder6 without path1 and path2? I try this command `tar -czvf f.tar.gz -C path1 . -C path2 .` but not help

Comment: Instead of writing "but not help", it would be better to explain what happens, to give a clue for readers to understand and debug the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write like this:

```
tar zcvf f.tar.gz -C /path1 . -C /path2 .
```

That is, it's important to use the absolute paths of `/path1` and `/path2`.